# Docker running and accessible on the local machine with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile but not in the VPS server

Tags: server, apache2, php, docker, vps

I am configuring the docker to my projects in the VPS server for the first time. I successfully run it on a local machine but in the server, all services are running but not accessible through the browser. I checked all the port mapping, firewall configurations, and lots of blogs and tutorials but nothing help me out.

Below is the structure of my project:

- html/

  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
  - projects (ie. oms)

    - project files

Here are my configuration files,
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  oms:
    build:
      context: . # automatically finds Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: oms
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - "./oms:/var/www/html/oms"
    links:
     - db
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6.13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root #username = root
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin: 
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST:db
      - PMA_PORT:3306
volumes:
  db:
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && apt-get install -y nano \
    && apt-get install -y iputils-ping


# Give permissions to www-data user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Enable rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Copy the project files for projects(ie office1, office2..)
COPY ./ /var/www/html/

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Restart Apache service
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

when i try to access through browser using url http://ip:8001 or http://ip:8080, it throw me this error

[image: error]

I checked whether the port is blocked or not by the firewall using the command:

- telnet vps_ip 8080
- telnet vps_ip 8001

both ports are connected

Also, when I login into the VPS server and curl -i localhost:8001 in the terminal it displays contents but not in the browser. I don't know what I am missing. Can somebody please help me out?